# How to put loading in mootools?

Tags: mootools

now i want create slideshow banner with mootools and i want to put loading image, mean after all images is loaded then start show all images (with slideshow).

My question is how to put LOADING ?

here my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-1.2.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready',function() {
            /* settings */
            var $xxa = jQuery.noConflict();

            var showDuration = 3000;
            var container = $('slideshow-container');
            var images = container.getElements('img');
            var currentIndex = 0;
            var interval;
            /* opacity and fade */
            images.each(function(img,i){ 
                if(i > 0) {
                    img.set('opacity',0);
                }
            });
            /* worker */
            var show = function() {
                images[currentIndex].fade('out');
                images[currentIndex = currentIndex < images.length - 1 ? currentIndex+1 : 0].fade('in');
            };
            /* start once the page is finished loading */
            window.addEvent('load',function(){
                interval = show.periodical(showDuration);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you want this in mootools, why tag it jquery and jquery-ajax? *Retagged*

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the mootools-more `Asset.images` from Asset.js

it can load multiple images and it fires onprogress / oncomplete events for the lot. http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets#Asset:Asset-images

what you do implies the images have loaded already - the `load` will trigger after all is done if they are in the dom - but it will wait for other elements as well as your images of interest, so that's a little wasteful

you can still create a new Element on domready saying 'loading' and destroy it onload, keep your code as is.

eg.

```
var loader = new Element("div", { 
    html: "loading..."
    tween: {
        onComplete: function() {
            this.element.destroy();
        }
    }
}).inject(document.id("sometarget")); 
...
window.addEvent('load', function(){ 
    loader.fade('out'); // will fade and destroy it.
    interval = ...
});
```